# App Service -> Azure SQL DB using a managed identity. Strange exception

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-managed-identity

I am trying to set up a connection from my App Service to Azure SQL DB with managed identity.
I am using this tutorial
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-connect-msi
But when my app tries to connect to the database it breaks with exception

```
One or more errors occurred.;
INNER EXCEPTION 1: One or more errors occurred.;
INNER EXCEPTION 2: Parameters: Connection String: [No connection string specified], Resource: https://database.windows.net/, Authority: https://login.windows.net/B0BBBC89-2041-434F-8618-BC081A1A01D4. Exception Message: Tried the following 4 methods to get an access token, but none of them worked.
Parameters: Connection String: [No connection string specified], Resource: https://database.windows.net/, Authority: https://login.windows.net/B0BBBC89-2041-434F-8618-BC081A1A01D4. Exception Message: Tried to get token using Managed Service Identity. Access token could not be acquired. Received a non-retryable error. MSI ResponseCode: BadRequest, Response: {\"StatusCode\":400,\"Message\":\"No MSI found for specified ClientId/ResourceId.\",\"CorrelationId\":\"ad10102e-dd69-479e-b9f5-29b9a3248983\"}
Parameters: Connection String: [No connection string specified], Resource: https://database.windows.net/, Authority: https://login.windows.net/B0BBBC89-2041-434F-8618-BC081A1A01D4. Exception Message: Tried to get token using Visual Studio. Access token could not be acquired. Visual Studio Token provider file not found at \"D:\\local\\LocalAppData\\.IdentityService\\AzureServiceAuth\\tokenprovider.json\"
Parameters: Connection String: [No connection string specified], Resource: https://database.windows.net/, Authority: https://login.windows.net/B0BBBC89-2041-434F-8618-BC081A1A01D4. Exception Message: Tried to get token using Azure CLI. Access token could not be acquired. 'az' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
Parameters: Connection String: [No connection string specified], Resource: https://database.windows.net/, Authority: https://login.windows.net/B0BBBC89-2041-434F-8618-BC081A1A01D4. Exception Message: Tried to get token using Active Directory Integrated Authentication. Access token could not be acquired. Failed to get user name from the operating system.
```

Does anyone know where to look for the cause?

Comment: Have you add the Azure MSI as Azure SQL database contained user:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-configure?tabs=azure-powershell#create-contained-users-mapped-to-azure-ad-identities?

Comment: Do you have any update/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We understand what the problem is.
The article deals with system-assigned managed identity. We use user-assigned managed identitiy.
The app service has not been configured correctly.
On the identification tab, it was necessary to add a user account who has access to the database.
On the configuration tab, it was necessary to add a key

```
AzureServicesAuthConnectionString=RunAs=App;AppId={Guid of db user}
```